# Didn't change the length of Array after push in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

please help me with weird behavior. I declare an Array:
  buildsArray = new Array();

And add the objects item in the Array like this:

```
  var detailBuild = {
              id: elements.data.id,
              username: (elements.data.triggered.user) ? elements.data.triggered.user.username : "not user",
              project: (elements.data.buildType) ? elements.data.buildType.projectName : "not project",
              status: elements.data.status
            };
            buildsArray.push(detailBuild);
```

But after push, the length property of my array is equal to 0. although the

```
console.log (buildsArray);
console.log ("the length of buildsArray is " + buildsArray.length);
```

show me this:
[image]

Please tell me what did I do wrong, thanks

The full code:

```
 return promise.then((elements) => {
        console.log (elements.data.build);
        elements.data.build.forEach(element => {

          var detailpromise = httpService.getBuildDetail(element.href);
          detailpromise.then((elements) => {

            var detailBuild = {
              id: elements.data.id,
              username: (elements.data.triggered.user) ? elements.data.triggered.user.username : "not user",
              project: (elements.data.buildType) ? elements.data.buildType.projectName : "not project",
              status: elements.data.status
            };
            buildsArray.push(detailBuild);
            var item = buildsGroupingByProject.find(element => element.projectName === detailBuild.project);
            (item === undefined) ?
            buildsGroupingByProject.push({
                projectName: detailBuild.project,
                buildArrays: new Array(detailBuild)
              })
              :
              item.buildArrays.push(detailBuild);

          });
        });
        console.log (buildsArray);
        console.log ("the length of buildsArray is " + buildsArray.length);
        return buildsGroupingByProject;
      });
    }
```

Comment: Please post a full [MCVE] - I bet there's an asynchronous call in there

Comment: _"But after push"_ Is `console.log (buildsArray);` executed directly beneath `buildsArray.push(detailBuild);` in the actual code?

Comment: Yes, I do this inside a Promise.then function. I can post the full code rigth now

Comment: I have a feeling that this is the result of confusion around asynchronous code. Most likely, at the moment `console.log(buildsArray)` runs, the array actually *is* empty, but by the time you expand that line in the console, new items have been pushed to it.

Comment: Yeah so my suspicion was right. You'll need [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and only do your `console.log` inside a final `then`.

Comment: I begining to undestand the problem, but how can I wait the async functions before return the array?

Comment: You don't return the array. You return a promise which will resolve to the array once it's been fully populated.